# Static HTML server side template rendering framework

Tags: javascript, php, html, performance

I have an 8 page website generated from a theme forest HTML template that I want to restructure so that:

1. Common elements such as navigation, headers, footers, and sliders are created from one template file rather than have to be edited 8 times, once per page. Variables are NOT needed for the template, just a simple include or equivalent.
2. CSS and JS are linted, combined, minified, gzipped where common across the 8 pages.  The template includes Bootstrap 3.x, jQuery, various CSS and JS files.
3. Optional - nice url e.g. `/about` and `/gallery` rather than about.html and gallery.html

I don't mind PHP or Javascript etc to generate the static pages, but I don't want to implement a full framework nor render the HTML templates client side.  I want Google and the users to get exactly the same page view, and I want the static client to be downloaded in minified format from a dumb server.

I am going to use Gulp for item 2 unless someone suggests something better. Currently the client has to download just over a megabyte of JS & CSS.

I could use slim framework and twig for item 1 and 3, but that seems like complete overkill and if possible I want everything already rendered and I just run a gulp or npm task to rebuild it as needed.

Comment: What is your question? If you're asking for framework recommendations, you know it's off-topic at SO?

Comment: I don't want a framework. Will edit

Comment: Just found what I wanted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708986/gulp-html-templates-and-fragment-loading so I did a vote to close